# Install a MU plugin from within another plugin

Tags: plugin-development, mu-plugins

I am writing a plugin that needs to disable another plugin on specific pages of the site.  I know how to do this using the `option_active_plugins` filter, but that filter only works from an MU plugin.

So is it possible to programatically install a MU plugin from my main plugin so that I can run this filter?  Or is there another way to tackle this?